# Can a floating image follow the text?

Tags: html, css

I want to float an image to the right of some text. It looks like the image only floats correctly when it precedes the text in the html.

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
    float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
    float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what it looks like on codepen, with enough text so you can see whether the float is working: [Example](http://codepen.io/tomcockerline/pen/gWYKGa)

This is a problem because I have written a js function that toggles the image from a thumbnail floating right to a full size image and I want the full size image under the text, not above it.

Comment: Nope. Text and inline elements that come *after* the floated element will wrap around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who contributed! Here is how I resolved it:

Create two figure containers for the image. The first figure is before the text and the second figure is after the text. The first figure uses a class with css that floats it right and makes it small. The second figure uses a class with no float and full display size. The first figure initially has "display:block" and the second figure "display:none", so you only see the thumbnail when the page loads.

Each figure has its own onclick js function, the purpose of which is to hide itself by setting "display:none" for its own class and display the other figure by setting it to "display:block".

```js
function displayImage(myObj) {
 /* myObj is the thumbnail img object */
 objParent = myObj.parentElement
 objImage = objParent.getElementsByClassName("fullImage")[0];
  /* Remove the classname so the Div doesn't use display: flex. */
 objParent.className = "";
 /* Display the image */
 objImage.attributes.style.value = "display:block"
 /* Hide the thumbnail */
 myObj.attributes.style.value = "display:none"
}

function displayThumbnail(myObj) {
 /* myObj is the full img object */
 objParent = myObj.parentElement
 objThumbnail = objParent.getElementsByClassName("thumb")[0];
 /* Add the classname so the Div uses display: flex. */
 objParent.className = "clearfix";
 /* Display the thumbnail */
 objThumbnail.attributes.style.value = "display:block"
 /* Hide the image */
 myObj.attributes.style.value = "display:none"
}
```

```css
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.float-figure-right {
 float: right;
 width: 10%;
}

figure {
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: smaller;
  text-indent: 0;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

figure.thumb {
 min-width: 10%;
 max-width: 10%;
 border: thin #882529 solid;
 padding: 0.25em;
}

figure.thumb:hover {
 min-width: 11%;
 max-width: 11%;
 border: thin #882529 dotted;
}

figure.thumb > img{
 width: auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="clearfix">
  <figure class="thumb float-figure-right" style="display:block" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onclick="displayImage(this)">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250"
    width=50 height=50>
  </figure>
 <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
 </p>
  <figure class="fullImage" style="display:none" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onclick="displayThumbnail(this)">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
   <figcaption>Caption for the full image</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your floats are working as they should actually. 
Floats work by taking the element out of the normal flow and positioning it on the edge of the container by the direction you specify. The reason why the first one looks "off" is because your img tag is already at the end of the container. . . no where else for it to really go.

On the other hand when you have the img as the first element in the paragraph the float property on it is more actively taking that element and moving it to the other side of the container. Hope that makes sense you can read more about floats here [MDN Float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Comment: This is correct. Moving the image in the middle of the long paragraph will make it float to the right of the text as expected. +1 on that, I couldn't figure this out and it was simple.

Comment: gwar9, Thanks for your explanation and link to MDN, which clarified the situation for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a js function that toggles the image from a thumbnail floating right to a full size image, you should use this function to move your image from before to after your content. This solution can support cross browsers.

If you want to solve it by CSS and target to modern browsers, you can follow [StefanBob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355456/can-a-floating-image-follow-the-text/43355581#43355581)'s answer.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  document.querySelectorAll('article')
    .forEach(function (article) {
      let thumbnail = article.querySelector('.thumb');
      thumbnail.src = thumbnail.dataset.src;
    
      article.classList.add('full');
      article.appendChild(thumbnail);
    })
  ;
}, 3000);
```

```css
.thumb {
  float: right;
}

article {
  clear: both;
}

.full img {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
  
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" data-src="http://placehold.it/480x360" class="thumb">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius illo at, ducimus expedita similique, hic, ratione voluptates veniam esse ullam, architecto vero quaerat tenetur officiis neque! Inventore architecto, quibusdam at. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius illo at, ducimus expedita similique, hic, ratione voluptates veniam esse ullam, architecto vero quaerat tenetur officiis neque! Inventore architecto, quibusdam at.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius illo at, ducimus expedita similique, hic, ratione voluptates veniam esse ullam, architecto vero quaerat tenetur officiis neque! Inventore architecto, quibusdam at. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius illo at, ducimus expedita similique, hic, ratione voluptates veniam esse ullam, architecto vero quaerat tenetur officiis neque! Inventore architecto, quibusdam at.</p>
</article>

<article>
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
  
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" data-src="http://placehold.it/480x360" class="thumb">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius illo at, ducimus expedita similique, hic, ratione voluptates veniam esse ullam, architecto vero quaerat tenetur officiis neque! Inventore architecto, quibusdam at. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius illo at, ducimus expedita similique, hic, ratione voluptates veniam esse ullam, architecto vero quaerat tenetur officiis neque! Inventore architecto, quibusdam at.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius illo at, ducimus expedita similique, hic, ratione voluptates veniam esse ullam, architecto vero quaerat tenetur officiis neque! Inventore architecto, quibusdam at. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius illo at, ducimus expedita similique, hic, ratione voluptates veniam esse ullam, architecto vero quaerat tenetur officiis neque! Inventore architecto, quibusdam at.</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Pig Ball, thanks for this code snippet. I decided to go with a different implementation, but this got me thinking in a new direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the `img` out of the `p` tag, add a container div around it, and use flexbox. When your image is changed to 100% add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the `div`, with a class would be easy, and let the image go underneath like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
    <img src="blah">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.container.full-image {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, StefanBob. I was able to get it working using your method, but decided to go with a different implementation that doesn't require flex support in the browser.

Comment: You're welcome, no problem. Flexbox is supported in all major browsers now btw http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is move the image before the text that you want it to float over, like this.

```css
img {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<p>In the paragraph below, we have a paragraph with text followed by an image with style <b>float:right</b>. The float doesn't work. In the next paragraph, the image precedes the text and the float works. Can an image only be floated when it precedes the text?</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
```